# Django Query with Case Insensitive Data Both Ways

Tags: django, django-queryset, case-insensitive

There are a lot of similar questions, but I'm only finding partial solutions.
I have a group of users stored as objects, with a name attribute (User.name).  I'm hoping to do a query with a user input (Foo) such that I can (without being case sensitive) find all users where either:

1. foo is in User.name
2. User.name is in foo

As an example, I want the user to be able to type in "Jeff William II" and return "Anderson Jeff William II", "jeff william iii", as well as "Jeff Will" and "william ii"

I know I can use the [Q function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to combine two queries, and I can use annotate() to transform User.name like so (though I welcome edits if you notice errors in this code):

`users = User.objects.annotate(name_upper=Upper(name)).filter(Q(name_upper__icontains=foo) | Q(name_upper__in=foo))`

But I'm running into trouble using `__in` to match multiple letters within a string.  So if User.name is "F" I get a hit when inputting Jeff but if User.name is "JE" then it doesn't show up.  How do I match multiple letters, or is there a better way to make this query?

SIDE NOTE: I initially solved this with the following, but would prefer making a query if possible.

```
for u in User.objects.all():
     if u.name in foo or foo in u.name:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do *not* use `Upper`. It is a common misconception that by converting two items to uppercase (or lowercase) you make a case insenstive equality check. Certain characters, like ß have no uppercase/lowercase, and have more complicated rules (collation) to consider these equivalent. In Python one uses [**`.casefold(…)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) for that.

For the database, you can simply make use of annotate, and then use two checks:

```
from django.db.models import CharField, F, Q, Value

foo = 'Jeff William II'

User.objects.annotate(foo=Value(foo, CharField())).filter(
    Q(name__icontains=foo) | Q(foo__icontains=F('name'))
)
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble with implementation (and my apologies if there's more standard SO follow up protocol).  Do I need to be using `foo=Value(foo, CharField)`?

Comment: @nbixler: sorry, `Value(foo, CharField())` (so a `CharField` *object).